# How can I randomly generate a date for sometime over the last 30 days?

Tags: c#, datetime, random

I have a variable named d that I am currently giving the value:

```
var a = DateTime.Now;
```

How can I make it so that the variable gets a different date between now and the last 30 days at random each time the variable is set?

Answer (score 13):

```
Random r = new Random();
var a = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1 * r.Next(30));
```

Note that the Next(30) will never return the value of 30 itself since the `Next` function parameter is an *exclusive* value.  Your statement "the last 30 days" is a bit ambiguous...   If you aren't including "today" in the last 30 days, then you'll just need to add 1 and make it `r.Next(31)`.

Comment: Hopefully time doesn't matter.

Comment: I have found that many people use DateTime.Now when they don't care about the time, and the OP's wording seemed to indicated that a date was desired.

Comment: Would be interesting to see how `(-r.Next(30))` works under the hood, might save on that multiplication

Comment: @musefan: `-x` is essentially the same as `0-x`. But why is multiplication something you need to save?  The amount of work those two lines are doing is *immense* compared to the multiplication; trying to "save" on that work is like trying to save on water by not watering one of the blades of grass in your lawn.

Comment: @EricLippert: Thanks, you are officially quicker than Google! ...on this day

Comment: @EricLippert: I don't really care for the saving so much, but `-x` would have been my natural approach, and I like to know how things like this compare. Just like using `Today` over `Now` if time is not required. Nobody cares about that performance difference, but people like to know they are kicking ass when they use the slightly more suitable one

Comment: @musefan: I agree...  FWIW, I've never used the `-x` syntax because I figured it was the same as multiplication, and for some reason I can't explain I don't like the way it looks on screen.  But thanks for pointing it out - I learned something today!  :)

Comment: Perhaps because I come from a mathematical background, I find `-x` easier to read than `-1 * x`. Or maybe it's just because it's shorter...

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I also have math background - in fact I tutor math as a side-job.  Like I said - I can't explain why I don't like it.  :)

Comment: @musefan: The chip will actually implement `x - y` as `x + (-y)` for integers, so there's no getting away from the unary minus. It really doesn't matter whether you say `-y` or `0-y` or `-1*y` or `(-1)*y` or whatever; trust that the compiler is smart enough to generate good code.